# Why does my loglikelihood dip during training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a model that contains two neural networks: one is computing the mean of a function as a function over `x` and the other is computing the sd of that function as a function over `x`. The model computes the loglikelihood of a pair `x` and `y` (using Gaussian pdf of the mean and sd at that value of `x`). I train the model using a gradient descent method that tries to maximise this loglikelihood at each step. Plotting epoch against mean loglikelihood shows something interesting. The loglikelihood initially increases rapidly and then plateaus as expected. However, beyond a certain point there are 'dips' in the mean loglikelihood.

[image: Epoch against mean log likelihood]

What is causing these dips? Each step aims to maximise log likelihood yet some of the steps are decreasing it. I have a similar model that uses a single value for sd rather than a function over x and it doesn't demonstrate these dips.

Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
url = 'https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2122/DataSci/data/xkcd.csv'
xkcd = pandas.read_csv(url)
x,y = torch.tensor(xkcd.x, dtype=torch.float)[:,None], torch.tensor(xkcd.y, dtype=torch.float)[:,None]

class MyNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.f = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1,4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(4,20),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(20,20),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(20,1)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.f(x)

class MyLL(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.μ = MyNN()
        self.σpre = MyNN()
  def σ(self, x):
    return torch.nn.functional.softplus(self.σpre(x))
  def forward(self, y, x):
        σ2 = torch.pow(self.σ(x), 2)
        return - 0.5*torch.log(2*np.pi*σ2) - torch.pow(y - self.μ(x), 2) / (2*σ2)

torch.manual_seed(0)
model = MyLL()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
logliks = []

for _ in range(10000):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loglik = torch.mean(model(y, x))
  logliks.append(loglik.detach())
  (-loglik).backward()
  optimizer.step()

plt.plot(logliks)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's an interesting question, but you haven't told us much that would be useful in understanding this behavior. Can you share the data and code that would allow a person to reproduce that plot?

Comment: @Sycorax I have added code that produces the graph

Comment: your network should regress/output $\log \sigma$ instead of $\sigma$

Comment: Shimao is correct -- there's lots of places where you're accumulating numerical error. This might explain the results.

Comment: @shimao it outputs the log-likelihood not σ. I have been given this system and asked why there are the dips so it's not due to an error in the code.